# In RxJava, how do I start a potentially infinite stream of events generated from an API?

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I have an API available to clients that can be simplified to this:

```
public class API {
  public void sendEvent(Event e);
}
```

`Event` instances enter my system whenever a client calls the API (technically over Binder into a `Service` derivative) which are then processed, filtered and dispatched to other internal components. I don't care about past events, just those available from the time a subscriber subscribes. It seems like a natural fit for the Rx paradigm which I'm just getting my feet wet with.

I need an Observable that is created once, allows multiple subscribers, and can be fed instances of `Event` that are then sent through the reactive pipeline to observers. A `Subject` seems appropriate for what I'm looking to do (in particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14406666/562139) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14396449/562139) resonated with me).

What do other RxJava users recommend?

Comment: depends. do you want to cache the events, or only serve those available from the moment the subscriber has subscribed?

Comment: The latter. I don't care about past events, just events available from the time a subscriber subscribes.

Comment: typically, you'll have to return an Observable created from something that implements `OnSubscribe` (probably the same class as you API, but possibly a delegate of that class). In the `call(Subscriber)` method, you'll register a new subscriber (add it to a list). Then, whenever `sendEvent` is called, call `onNext` on all your subscriber from your list. Bonus: remove subscribers if `isUnsubscribed` return true.

Comment: That was where I was heading, and it seemed like I'd be reimplementing logic that I thought might already exist in RxJava. Doesn't a subject do these things already? Then I'd just call `onNext` on it and it would pass things along to the subscribers...

Comment: possibly `publish` can handle the spreading for you, but the initial bridge between your data and the publish, you still have to do it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For example, following on my short comment:

```
public class API implements OnSubscribe<Event> {
    private List<Subscriber<Event>> subscribers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void sendEvent(Event event) {
        // Do whatever you need with the event
        for (Subscriber<Event> sub : subscribers) {
            sub.onNext(event);
        }
    }
    public void call(Subscriber<Event> sub) {
        subscribers.add(sub);
    }
}
```

Then you probably have an instance somewhere: `API api = ...`

Your Observable is obtained like so: `Observable.create(api);` You can then do any normal thing you would do with an Observable.

The filtering of the unsubscribed `Subscriber`s is left as an exercise to the reader.

### Edit

A little more research shows that `PublishSubject` should help:

```
public class API {
    private PublishSubject<Event> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    public void sendEvent(Event event) {
        // Do whatever you need with the event
        // Then publish it
        subject.onNext(event);
    }
    public Observable<Event> getObservable() {
        return subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

This way, you can subscribe to this Observable, and every time an event is sent to `API`, it is published to all subscribers.

Use like this:

```
API api = ...;
api.getObservable().subscribe(event -> doStuffWithEvent(event));
api.getObservable().subscribe(event -> doOtherStuffWithEvent(event));
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. It looks reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try `observable.share()` which under the covers calls `.publish().refCount()`. It will use only one underlying subscription and give you the multiple subscription behaviour you specified.