# how can I convert this to use Rx rather than .NET style events?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

As per an earlier question, I was told by a user that I [should not expose a .NET Event-style API unless absolutely forced to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23789538/1073868):

> If you're not positively forced to do so, do not make an API using C# style events.

In this case, how should I implement an "event" whereby a model will notify any observers that it has changed in some way? The event is only expected to be called **once**. Let's say for example that my model is a Minecraft Block, and I invoke the method `Destroy()` on this model. The `Destroy()` method should broadcast to it's observers that that model intends to be destroyed. Example observers would be a controller that would then send a `BlockDestroyed` notification to the view (I appreciate the controller could be an unnecessary level of indirection however it is a lot easier to do model -> controller -> view rather than model (observable) -> view (observer)).

Here is my code that I would intend to alter to an Rx style - remember, `Destroyed` would only be invoked once per block - and there could be other events, such as `Damaged`, `Activated`, and `TextureChanged`.

```
public class Block
{
    public Block()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Destroy the block.
    /// </summary>
    public void Destroy()
    {
        var msg = new BlockDestroyedMessage();
        if (Destroyed != null)
            Destroyed(this, msg);
    }

    public event EventHandler<BlockDestroyedMessage> Destroyed;
}
```

Also note that I am seeing documentation over the web that basically you

- Should avoid `ISubject<T>` because it encourages violating the SRP (which I agree with)
- Don't implement `IObservable<T>` (because there are so many factory methods for creating observables)

Comment: You may be misinterpreting the advice you have seen.  Avoid *exposing* an `ISubject<T>` if you are only pushing events (and not receiving).  You can, and often should, use one as the underlying event source.  Expose it as an `IObservable<T>`.  (Expose `IObservable<T>`, but don't *implement* it yourself).

Comment: Ah right, I get you. I did see someone saying don't use `ISubject` at all as it indicates that you are doing something wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033378/reactive-trying-to-understand-how-subjectt-work/12034362#12034362

Comment: That answer raises some valid points, such that unhandled exceptions emanating from an observer's handler may wreck the subject and all its other subscriptions.  There are a lot of things to take into consideration, particularly with respect to error handing, multicasting, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
public class Block
{
    public void Destroy()
    {
        if (_destroyed != null)
        {
            var msg = new BlockDestroyedMessage();
            _destroyed.OnNext(msg);
            _destroyed.OnCompleted();
            _destroyed = null;
        }
    }
    private Subject<BlockDestroyedMessage> _destroyed
        = new Subject<BlockDestroyedMessage>();

    public readonly IObservable<BlockDestroyedMessage> Destroyed
        = _destroyed.AsObservable();
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I would have suggested, though I would expose the `IObservable` as a read-only property rather than a mutable field.

Comment: If `Destroy` could be called from multiple threads you'd want to wrap it in a `lock` block.

Comment: Sometimes, I hate concurrency. :(